# how to get selenium-grid node id and dockers-novnc port id mapping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, mapping, selenium-grid, novnc

I have started selenium docker compose file with `novnc` enabled and scaled the browser from 1 to 3.

I can get the session id and node id from the api `http://localhost:4444/status`. **But is there any way i can get the port mapping wrt node id?**

Step to reproduce:

1. Docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:latest
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=1
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=1
      - SE_VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=60
    ports:
      - "7901-7903:7900"
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"`
```

2. Start docker compose

`docker-compose -f docker-composer.yml up`

3. scale docker compose browser

`docker-compose -f docker-composer.yml up  --scale edge=3`

4. Trigger any test on remote url: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
5. Open any of the below url to see the live test running
   http://localhost:7901/ , http://localhost:7902/ , http://localhost:7903/
6. To get session id and node id trigger below api

`Get: http://localhost:4444/status`

I am expecting to get a mapping in between node id and the novnc port(7901-7903) so that in step 5 I exactly know which url I have to open to view my test rather than trying to open one by one and checking each of them.

Comment: I can see the real time test happening in http://localhost:7901/ , http://localhost:7902/ , http://localhost:7903/  But i dont know which test is getting triggered in which node and which node is being mapped to which port (7901/7902/7903)

Comment: Something i was able to figure out:

On triggering http://localhost:4444/status the value of node[i].uri and the novnc port number are always stored in ascending order with 1-1 mapping

but still i am trying to figure out a way to directly get the novnc port: node id mapping as the value of node[i].uri can start from any random number